# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, json, elasticsearch, typeerror

I don't know how to resolve my problem. I'm getting this error: 
`angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`

Every time I start my search query I am getting this error.

my `data.php` works well with the databank. What is the best way to resolve this. I don't know where I have to look in my code.

http://mida.uni-trier.de

Comment: The error clearly states the problem, you're trying to get the property 'total' of a value that is undefined. I had a quick look at your code and you don't check if it's undefined, so yes this can happen. Look in app/services/search.js on line 39

Comment: Your response return data:{
error:"IndexAlreadyExistsException[[fud_mida] already exists]"
status:400}

Comment: so result.data is available like above but result.data.hits.total; not available. hits is undefined then how u get total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are making request, you are getting exception "IndexAlreadyExistsException[[fud_mida] already exists]" and status 400. You can see it in "result.data".

At line number 39 in "search.js", you are setting "result.data.hits.total" in which there is not "hits" inside "result.data" object.

i.e : data.total = result.data.hits.total; // here hit doesn't exists.

That's why you getting error "**Cannot read property 'total' of undefined**".

either you can handle the exception before setting the data.total or remove the exception.

Debug your code in console, you will easily find the issue.

Hope it might help you.

Comment: i´ve deleted .total in `data.total = result.data.hits.total;` and now it looks like `data.total = result.data.hits;` . the error is gone but i dont get any results if i proceed the search now

Comment: have a look on result object returned, it doesn't contains any hit and you are trying to set the hits, that's why you getting none.